# Sublime Text 3 : Change font to myraid pro light

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3

I have downloaded `Myriad Pro` Regular, **Bold**, *Italic* and ***Bold Italic*** fonts and installed them on my Linux 12.04 system.

All I want to do is change my default sublime text font to `Myraid Pro Light`.

I have added an entry to `Preferences` >> `Settings - User`

```
"font_face": "Myraid Pro Light"
```

but the result is weired broken font and not at all.

How do I change to sleek fonts Myraid Pro Light.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: The most obvious suggestion would be to spell the font name correctly. It should be Myriad, not Myraid. But perhaps the misspelling is only in your SO question and not in the actual config?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Sublime after updating the user preference file worked for me, with another font.